# Return a sum of values common to an attribute in sql?

Tags: sql, database, aggregate-functions

I have some rows that looks like this:

```
name  value
------------
Name  1
Name  2.8
Name  8
```

I want my return to be one row:

```
name  value
------------
Name  11.8
```

How do I force this to be the case? 11.8 Being the sum of the values there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Value)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Name
```